# System.StackOverflowException from a simple EF6 query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I created a project that references a class library data layer project. The data layer is generated in `Visual Studio` using `Code First from database`:

> Add New Item => ADO.NET Entity Data Model => Code First from database

I have selected all tables from a huge database (~1000 tables) and at the moment when I try to get something from any of the tables, it just hangs and eventually throws `System.StackOverflowException`.

The query looks like that:

```
using (var context = new MyDbModel()) 
{
    var test = context.Student.FirstOrDefault(x => x.studentCode == "ONETWO"); 
    // code is unique, it starts hanging here
}
```

Running this statement in `SSMS` takes less than a second. 
`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Student WHERE studentCode = "ONETWO"`

I suppose this causes loading the whole database and therefore the exception, but how can I avoid that?

Comment: You're pretty much answering your own question: make multiple smaller contexts.

Comment: Code first? If so, please make sure you haven't introduced a stack overflow in a setter of a property on one of the models.

Comment: @GertArnold Chances are that I'll never need these 1000 tables, but I will probably need a significant number of them due to the size of the application. It is easier to add the whole model in one class library project and then have all other applications reference it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Should I not use Code First? I think it's impossible to go through all setters of all 1000 generated model classes.

Comment: No, what Lasse refers to is setters that set themselves. Than can happen sometimes when writing code. It's not likely here because you get the error no matter what you do. AS for the amount of tables -- the class library may as well contain multiple contexts. I'd seriously consider doing that. The database *must* consist of a couple of logical aggregates.