# Linq to SQL with externe database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a desktop application build in C#. But the time goes on and it is time to make the desktop application web based(new application). So for porting the desktop application to web based I am using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework. The application make use of a existing datbase. But the database is very huge. Like 500 tables. I wonder if I can use LinqToSQL in EF, so that you can use the objects, like this for example:

```
 public  ActionResult Create(Climb climb)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {                   

                            db.Climbs.Add(climb);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                        }
                    }

            catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
            }

            SetCountryDifficultViewBag(climb.CountryId, climb.DifficultId);
            return View(climb);

        }
```

But this of course are the already existing models from a other project. But of course in the new application I don't have the models.

So I tried to import the database in the project with the wizard: Entity data Model Wizard. See image:[image]

But that was not so good idea. Because I got the error: Too much memory is in use. And also the size of the db, like 500 mb.

So I am now using classic slq, like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index  (int? SelectedVestiging)       
        {


            var query = "SELECT Code, Name from [Verploegen TEST$Location]";
            Vestiging vestiging = await db.Vestigingen.SqlQuery(query, SelectedVestiging).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (vestiging == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var allITems = db.Vestigingen
                 .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.Code, Text = s.Code }).ToList();
            ViewBag.WestVigs = allITems;

            return View(vestiging);



        }
```

This query works
The above example is to show the Locations. The table of Location has the properties:`Code and Name`. 
And my model that I made for Location is like this:

```
public class Vestiging
    {
        //public int VestigingID { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


    }
```

But of course I also use queries with more linked tables. So I have two questions:

1.Can I use LINQ? Or I have to stick with classic SQL
2. The model I used for querying the Location is that good? OR is it better to use ViewModels?

Comment: EF(6) doesn't care about the amount of tables. It simply doesn't matter if there are 5 or 500 tables. Linq just helps you to make your queries type safe. so if you miss-type, then the intelli sense will correct you. in bare SQL you only get a runtime error

Comment: Well, it does matter how many tables the database has. You better try to make smaller contexts for distinct parts of your application. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/q/39014320/861716

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But How can I import the database? And is it necessary to import the whole db in the project? Or can I use LINQ without importing the whole DB in the project? Because how I did it, see the image in the post, I got and error that it was using to much memory. ANd also if you include the db in the project, the project will become very large. SO what is the best way then to use the DB? THank you

Comment: ?? I don't get so much replies. Very strange. Sorry, but I am not clear what I mean? Sorry, but If I not clear now what I mean. Want you want then?

Comment: So is it possible, to use LINQ with an externe database? Not included in the project. Thank you

Comment: @SavantCode I happen to see this now. Others are only notified if you use `@name` in your comment. When you create an edmx you can select the tables you want to have in there. I don't know if you need the whole db, if you do, create a number "small" edmx's containing tables grouped by to the various task areas in your application.

Comment: But I only use now one table

Comment: So create an edmx with this *one* table. By the way, I'd prefer the option Code First from database.

Comment: But I already have that.